# Flatness over a perfectoid ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, p-adic-analysis

I want to prove the following: Let $R$ be a  perfectoid ring and $\varpi$ a pseudo uniformizer in $R$ which admits all $p$-th power roots, then a module over $R^\circ$ is flat if and only if it has no $\varpi$ nontrivial torsion.
(I know this is true when $R$ is a  perfectoid field.)

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you add dollar-symbols the LaTeX-like notation would actually render. You can do so via an [edit]

Comment: I 'm sorry to there used to be a typo ....

Comment: Why do you want to prove this? This is like asking if torsion-free modules over $\mathbf{Z}_p[\![x]\!]$ are flat, which is false. Consider $R=A[t^{p^{-\infty}}]^{\wedge}$ with $A=k\langle t \rangle$ for $k=\mathbf{C}_p$ and $\varpi=p$, so $R^0=A^0[t^{p^{-\infty}}]$ with $A^0=O_k\langle t \rangle$. Then the ideal $M = (p, t)$ in the domain $R$ is finitely presented as an $R$-module with generic fiber of dimension 1, so $M$ is flat if and only if it is invertible.  For the unique maximal ideal $J$ of $R^0$ containing $p$ and $t$, $M/JM$ is 2-dimensional over the field $R^0/J$, contradiction.

Comment: I want a friendly criterion to check flatness...

Comment: In fact, I hope to prove theorem 7.1.1 in Peter Scholze's lectures on p-adic geometry. I hope I can proceed as in his paper where I need to check flatness.

Comment: In my counterexample above there are some typos: a completion symbol missing in the description of $R^0$, and $M$ is meant to be taken as an ideal in $R^0$ (and viewed as an $R^0$-module).

Comment: Buzzard and Verberkmoes already proved that Theorem 7.1.1 and rather more in their preprint from some time ago (their method is written for perfectoid algebras over fields but adapts with minor changes to work in general: see 13.4ff in the notes at http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/Perfseminar/Notes/L13.pdf), and no such flatness criterion is needed for what they do. Scholze's lecture notes give the reference to that preprint.

Comment: Thanks. You example make things clear. However, I think such a  criterion will be interesting.

Comment: @ConglingQiu: Unless one has guidance coming from more familiar commutative algebra (e.g., have an analogue in mind for higher-dimensional local noetherian domains), it seems unlikely to expect to find such a criterion.

Comment: @ user74230: is there any chance that "if $S/R$ are 2 perfectoid, then $S^\circ/R^\circ$ is flat" is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in the case $R$ and $S$ are perfectoid algebras over a perfectoid field, it's not the case that $S$ is $R$-flat in many situations, eg. perf $R$, take a higher rank point in $\text{Spa}(R,R^0)$, look at the completed res field $\kappa$, at the $\kappa$-normalization $\kappa^+$ of $R^0$, and finally at the map $R^0\to\kappa^+$.

If $R$ is a perfectoid algebra over a perfectoid field $K$, $K^0$-flatness conveniently comes for free for $R^0$. You want to use it to check that ``derived relative perfectness'':

$$A_{\varphi}\otimes_{\varphi, A}^{\mathbf{L}} B\xrightarrow{\simeq} B_{\varphi}[0]$$

in $\text{D}(B)$, $A$, $B$ $\mathbf{F}_p$-algebras, $\varphi$ the abs Frobenius, $A_{\varphi}$ is $A$ as an $A$-algebra under $\varphi$, same for $B$, is met when $A = K^0/\varpi$ and $B = R^0/\varpi$. This is obvious in deg $0$, and if $K$ is a perfectoid field also in higher degs by $K^0$-flatness of $R^0$. From here it's an easy lemma that $\mathbf{L}_{(R^0/\varpi)/(K^0/\varpi)}\simeq 0$ in $\text{D}(R^0/\varpi)$.

For $K$ a perfectoid ring, you can't directly invoke derived rel perfectness and such vanishing lemma, and it's honestly not so clear why you should hunt flatness at all costs to make it available again.

Rather, you should reduce to the char $p$ case where perfect $\mathbf{F}_p$-algebras are derived relatively perfect. From this you show that if $R$ is perfectoid and $S$ is a perfectoid $R$-algebra, then the analytic cotangent complex of $R^0\to S^0$ as introduced in Gabber and Ramero's book on Almost Ring Theory, always vanishes.